# Syntax for float format string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, format

I want to use the `to_csv()` function in pandas to create a csv string from a dataframe. The function has a `float_format` parameter to control how floats are formatted in the output. However, I cannot find any documentation about how to use this parameter.

The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) helpfully only says "Format string for floating point numbers". I have tried searching the whole pandas documentation for "float_format" but found only references to the term and a few examples, such as in [IO tools](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html?highlight=float_format) or [options and settings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html?highlight=float_format), no explanation or definition. It is used in many other functions as well but it does not seem to be documented at all.

Can anyone point me to a documentation of the `float_format` parameter in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some information concerning the values that `float_format` can take in the python docs. More specifically in the section for the Format Specification Mini-Language. The link is : [Format Specification Mini-Language.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). It is not pandas docs but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Arpel - I'm fairly new to Python and wasn't aware of its string formatting feature.

Comment: This is not correct. The `'{}'` style format does not work, it requires the printf-style format (`'%f'`).